# How to verify QVariant of type QVariant::UserType is expected type?

Tags: qt, qvariant

I'm writing testing code that will automatically iterate thru all Q_PROPERTY's of widgets and some properties are using types that are registered via qRegisterMetaType. If i want to read/write these into QVariant i need to use QVariant::UserType when storing them into variant. So far so good.

But when i want to test reads and writes of these properties, i need to also know their type. For stuff that are already standard qt types, i can do this via QVariant::type() but as i have alot of usertypes, how would this be accomplished ?

From the api of QVariant, i spotted this:

`bool QVariant::canConvert ( Type t ) const`

But i'm slightly doubtful if this will lead to wrong types in case of enums?

So, what would be the foolproof way to verify what type of usertype is stored in QVariant ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For user defined types there is [QVariant::userType()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#userType). It works like QVariant::type() but returns the type id integer of the user defined type whereas QVariant::type() always return QVariant::UserType.

There is also [QVariant::typeName()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#typeName) which returns the name of the type as a string.

EDIT :

It probably depends on how you set the QVariant. Directly using [QVariant::QVariant(int type, const void * copy)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#QVariant-2) is discouraged.

Say I have three types like this :

```
class MyFirstType
{ 
    public:
        MyFirstType();
        MyFirstType(const MyFirstType &other);
        ~MyFirstType();

        MyFirstType(const QString &content);

        QString content() const;

    private:
        QString m_content;
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyFirstType);
```

The third without Q_DECLARE_METATYPE

I store them in QVariant :

```
 QString content = "Test";

 MyFirstType first(content);

 MySecondType second(content);

 MyThirdType third(content);

 QVariant firstVariant;
 firstVariant.setValue(first);

 QVariant secondVariant = QVariant::fromValue(second);

 int myType = qRegisterMetaType<MyThirdType>("MyThirdType");

 QVariant thirdVariant(myType, &third); // Here the type isn't checked against the data passed

 qDebug() << "typeName for first :" << firstVariant.typeName();
 qDebug() << "UserType :" << firstVariant.userType();
 qDebug() << "Type : " << firstVariant.type();

 [...]
```

I get :

```
typeName for first : MyFirstType 
UserType : 256 
Type :  QVariant::UserType 

typeName for second : MySecondType 
UserType : 257 
Type :  QVariant::UserType 

typeName for third : MyThirdType 
UserType : 258 
Type :  QVariant::UserType
```

Comment: However, it seems that in case of QVariant::UserType variant, typeName() method returns "UserType" and typeName() returns QVariant::UserType enum value. So both are useless

Comment: Object times are just fine, i can do the check also with typecasting so your example also propably works just fine. But my question was about enum's which isnt a class type and one can propably typecast any numeric variable into a enum.  But like said. I'll check your code.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't noticed that part. I tried and it looks like it's possible to register an enum type with Q_DECLARE_METATYPE or qRegisterMetaType and use it the same way. The docs only talk about class or struct with public default constructor, copy constructor and destructor, so I'm not completely sure, but I think it should work for any type that have the same implicit interface for creation, copy and destruction.