# QVariant userType() id

Tags: c++, qt

My question refers to:

[How to verify QVariant of type QVariant::UserType is expected type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193275/how-to-verify-qvariant-of-type-qvariantusertype-is-expected-type)

Specifically, if

```
struct MyType {
  ....
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyType);

QVariant v(QVariant::fromValue(MyType());
```

Is there a way to find out what `v.userType()` will return at compile-time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to find this out at compile time, because it's not determined until runtime.  You can get it with `qMetaTypeId<MyType>()`.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've tried, the indexes for `userType()` that are declared by you will start at 256, and then increase by one.

So if you use `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(someType);`, this type will then be returning `256` on `userType()` calls. If you then do `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(someOtherType);`, it will be returning `257` and so on.

Also, if you need to check it in the run-time, you can get the value once, and then use it for comparations:

```
int MyTypeID = QVariant::fromValue(MyType()).userType(); 
if( someObject.userType == MyTypeID )
{
//do stuff
}
```

You might also want to look at [qRegisterMetaType()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType-2) function.