# Dynamically typed container in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, containers

Is there a container who can store different types (yes, I really need to work with different kind of types) in Qt? I must create a new class to do this? If so, could you give me a hint to create it?

Comment: That would be QVariant.

Comment: Can I set a QVariant as a QMap?

Comment: Yes you can store `QMap<QString, QVariant>`or even user defined types, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193275/how-to-verify-qvariant-of-type-qvariantusertype-is-expected-type

Answer (score 1):

1. Most of containers in Qt are [template based](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/containers.html), then you can use them for different static types.
2. Another option is to use use [`QVariant`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qvariant.html), for example: `QVector<QVariant> vec;`.
3. A more dynamic solution is to use [polymorphism](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_polymorphism.htm), you can store pointers to a base class and so on.. .

---

*<sup>PS: As a general rule, you should avoid this patterns. From Effective C++, by Scott Meyers:</sup>*

> *<sup>Anytime you find yourself writing code of the form "if the object is
>   of type T1, then do something, but if it's of type T2, then do
>   something else," slap yourself.</sup>*