# Recover user-defined type stored in QVariant

Tags: qt

I've seen [How to verify QVariant of type QVariant::UserType is expected type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193275/how-to-verify-qvariant-of-type-qvariantusertype-is-expected-type) and I understand how to tell that an object of class MyType has been stored in a QVariant object. I've read the [documentation for QVariant::convert ()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#convert) but I don't follow how I call a member function defined in MyType for an object that I have received as a QVariant.

Say I have

```
class MyType
{
public:
    void myFunction;
    .
    .
    .
};
Q_DELCARE_METATYPE(MyType)
MyType m;
QVariant var (QVariant::fromValue (m));
```

How do I call MyType::myFunction for the MyType object saved at var?

Comment: Are you looking for [`QVariant::value`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#value)?  If not then please edit your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: You should convert your `QVariant` back to `MyType` in order to call its functions.

Comment: @G.M. I was indeed looking for QVariant::value. Thank you. I think I read through the member functions in alphabetical order and was cross-eyed by the time I got to that one. If you convert you comment to an answer, I will accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment, you can use [`QVariant::value`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#value) to obtain a copy of the object held by the `QVariant`.  So in this particular case something like...

```
/*
 * Check that the conversion is possible.
 */
if (var.canConvert<MyType>()) {

  /*
   * Obtain a copy of the MyType held.
   */
  auto m = var.value<MyType>();

  /*
   * Use as per normal.
   */
  m.myFunction();
}
```